# How can I separate this in bash?

Tags: bash

Say I have a script that puts out something like this

```
/path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3
/path/to/file4 /path/to/file5 /path/to/file6
/path/to/file91 /path/to/file23
/path/to/file130 /path/to/file34 /path/to/file/69 /path/to/file42
```

How can I take each line, and say, for example, run `rm` on everything *but* the first file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
script | while read first rest; do 
    echo rm $rest
done
```

Be sure to leave `$rest` unquoted so it is subject to word splitting.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
  your_script | sed 1d | xargs rm
```

This should work since rm takes multiple args,
so this is what will be executed :

```
# excluded by sed: /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 /path/to/file3
rm /path/to/file4 /path/to/file5 /path/to/file6 \
   /path/to/file91 /path/to/file23 \
   /path/to/file130 /path/to/file34 /path/to/file/69 /path/to/file42
```

If you want each word to be executed individually :

```
 for f in `your_script | sed 1d`; do rm $f; done
```

Which, as Smylers points out, is also achieved with:

```
  your_script | sed 1d | xargs -n 1 rm
```

Comment: actually, xargs will pass all the arguments together to single rm. (to check, create a dummy.sh file, containing `echo $#`. Then use that file instead of rm as argument to xargs.)

Comment: Which is why I added an example with `for`.

Comment: Oh... the reason for that comment was about the second quoted segment... "# excluded by sed... " section. xargs will not call rm line by line.

Comment: Instead of rewriting it as a `for` loop, you can simply do `xargs -n 1` to get the same effect.

Comment: You're right., I always forget that... I ought to add it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways:

```
your_script | tail -n +2 | xargs rm                      #Delete first line from stdout, run rm on other lines
your_script | { read x; xargs rm ; }                     #Read first line, ignore it. Run rm on others.
your_script | { read x; while read x; do rm $x; done ; } #Read first line, ignore it. Run rm on others, line by line. (slower...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_script|perl -F -ane 'shift @F if($.==1);print "@F"'|xargs rm -rf
```